# java program compiles, when run I get "JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, graphics, javafx, applet

I'm working from edition 6 Savitch text, it's question 17 page 250.  I'm a high school math teacher learning programming for the first time on my own.

The question is "17.  Create an applet that draws a pattern of circles whose centers are evenly spaced along a horizontal line.  Use six constants to control the pattern:  the number of circles to draw, the diameter of the first circle, the x- and y- coordinates of the center of the first circle, the distance between adjacent centers, and the change in the diameter of each subsequent circle."

I also tried copying the code of the example problem which was four pages long and got the same error, so I'm quite stuck.

Here's the code I attempted:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Pg250_17 extends JApplet
{
    public static final int CENTER_X_COORDINATE = 5;
    public static final int CENTER_Y_COORDINATE = 30;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES = 6;
    public static final int INCREMENT_DIA = 20;
    public static final int DIAMETER_FIRST = 2;
    public static final int DISTANCE_BETWEEN = 20;

    public void paint(Graphics canvas)
    {
        int i, xOffset, yOffset, newDiameter;
        for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; i++)
        {//Draw one circle
            xOffset = CENTER_X_COORDINATE + DISTANCE_BETWEEN * i;
            yOffset = CENTER_Y_COORDINATE;
            newDiameter = DIAMETER_FIRST + INCREMENT_DIA * i;
            canvas.drawOval(xOffset, yOffset, newDiameter, newDiameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are programming? With an IDE, like Netbeans or Eclipse? Maybe you have the wrong project type. JavaFX is not an Applet

Comment: Here's a link to a picture of the error I see.  http://imgur.com/u9XJTV2

Comment: Ok, how does your command line looks like to compile the sources? javac ...

Comment: Ah ok, you need to create a html file to call the jar, that's because it is an applet. An applet is typically called over the internet by requesting an html page with a special content. Have a look here, it is nicely explained: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/JavaInDOS.html

Comment: But be aware of some security restrictions in calling a html file with java applet from local. And for ex. Google Chrome will no longer enable Java NAPI (since version 42). And you have to explicitly allow your app to run localy from the java system preferences.